# How to troubleshoot failed API calls to .NET project running over localhost?

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, postman, endpoint

I have an API in a .NET project that I'm running with Visual Studio Mac (8.4.3). I run it in release mode, and it opens a browser window with `localhost:5000`. The browser window says "ok". However, when I try to hit endpoints in that API, it fails very quickly. When I ran this API (ie. same code) from another server and accessed it via proxy, it ran fine. For example, when I ran it on a server whose IP was `162.250.198.98` and proxied into it, I would hit an endpoint like `162.250.198.98:3000/api/user` and it would work, but now when I try to run `localhost:5000/api/user`, either from my app or from Postman, it fails almost instantaneously. When running it in Postman, I tried what it suggested by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings, but no change.

Can anyone advise me on how to approach troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 0):

Wait, so You are saying that while trying to call API on `162.250.198.98:`**3000**`/api/user` You are fine but while trying to do the same thing on `localhost:`**5000**`/api/user` You are getting an error? Would it might be possible You have Your API configured to receive calls at 3000? :)?

No, but really - please chech it out, maybe it is that simple, I'm couting on it :).

You can change/check it in Visual Studio: *main project* > **Properties** > **Debug** > **App URL**.